# "Closure takes 0 arguments" on a closure that takes an argument

Tags: rust

I am attempting to pass a closure to a function after a condition:

```
extern crate futures;
extern crate tokio_core;

use futures::prelude::*;
use futures::future;
use futures::unsync::*;

use tokio_core::reactor::*;

fn main() {
    let mut core = Core::new().unwrap();
    let h2 = core.handle();

    let fun = |should: Result<bool, ()>| {
        if should.unwrap_or(true) {
            // do something
        }

        future::ok(())
    };

    let (tx, rx) = oneshot::channel::<bool>();

    let dummy = true;

    if dummy {
        h2.spawn(rx.then(fun));
    } else {
        h2.spawn(future::ok(true).then(fun));
    }

    core.run(future::ok::<(), ()>(())).unwrap();
}
```

Here is [the code in the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=fa30a9eaefddc9bc389173c8386fc1b7&version=stable), but it is getting a different error from the error baffling me. My error looks like:

```
error[E0593]: closure takes 0 arguments but 1 argument is required
   --> src/client/forger.rs:123:25
    |
57  |           let fun = |should: Result<bool, ()>| {
    |  ___________________-
58  | |             if !should.unwrap_or(false) {
59  | |                 return Box::new(future::ok::<(), ()>(()));
60  | |             }
...   |
117 | |             Box::new(future::ok(()))
118 | |         };
    | |_________- takes 0 arguments
...
123 |               h2.spawn(rx.then(fun));
    |                           ^^^^ expected closure that takes 1 argument
```

Why does Rust say the function `fun` takes 0 arguments when it appears to quote it as taking one?

My Rust version is 1.22.1.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that my Rust version was 1.22.1, but the latest version is 1.23.0. This explains why the playground was returning a more accurate error: `expected signature of fn(std::result::Result<bool, futures::Canceled>) -> _`... which was the problem exactly.